# How to quantify the difference between two distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I wonder what are the ways for quantifying the distance between two (empirical) distributions?

For example, we can take two distributions in the range [0,1].

Thanks!

Comment: A simple way, based on Kormologrov-Smirnov test, would be to evaluate the maximum difference of the two at samplings points.

Comment: Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78405/measuring-distance-between-two-empirical-distributions